# How do I add a line of code to any script in my project?

Tags: c#, attributes

Hello stackoverflow forum,

how is it possible to add an attribute, like: [DoNotRename] above the class, but below the using directives to any script in my project?

**Here is an example:**

```
 //Using directives
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 //Attribute
 [DoNotRename] //<--------- (Above the class but below the usin directives)

 //Class
 public class Class_Name: MonoBehaviour
 {
 
 }
```

**How should an editor script look like to make that possible or is there already something similar?**

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles()` with `File.ReadAllLines()` or a thing more optimized, next insert needed line(s) and `File.WriteAllLines()`.

Comment: Could you explain why you want this? It seems like you're trying to achieve something that could be done in a smarter way